# Error: running qemu on powerpc

Tags: debian, virtualization, qemu, powerpc

I have installed qemu-0.13.0 on x86 system. I downloaded debian-powerpc image from http://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/powerpc/ and used it with this command

```
$qemu-system-ppc -hda debian_lenny_powerpc_small.qcow2 -nographic
```

This is the cpuinfo of the guest os (debian-507-powerpc (2.6.26-1-powerpc) )

```
processor    : 0
cpu        : 740/750
temperature     : 62-64 C (uncalibrated)
clock        : 1000.000000MHz
revision    : 3.1 (pvr 0008 0301)
bogomips    : 33.02
timebase    : 16600733
platform    : PowerMac
model        : Power Macintosh
machine        : Power Macintosh
motherboard    : AAPL,PowerMac G3 MacRISC
detected as    : 49 (PowerMac G3 (Silk))
pmac flags    : 00000000
pmac-generation    : OldWorld
```

After that, I installed qemu-0.13.0 on that guest os , and tried to run the same debian-powerpc image on it.

```
$qemu-system-ppc -hda debian_lenny_powerpc_small.qcow2 -nographic
```

The boot process got stuck with this:

```
>> =============================================================
>> OpenBIOS 1.0 [Dec 6 2009 11:39]
>> Configuration device id QEMU version 1 machine id 2
>> CPUs: 1
>> Memory: 128M
>> UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>> CPU type PowerPC,750
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.0 built on Dec 6 2009 11:39

Second-stage QUIK loader
Welcome to quik. mate is good.
Debian GNU/Linux PowerPCchosen/bootargs = Linux
boot: Linux 
initrd imagename = /initrd.img, mem_size: 7168568
initrd_start: 
Starting at 510000, , 13004800
OF stdout device is: /pci@80000000/mac-io@4/escc@13000/ch-b@13000
Preparing to boot Linux version 2.6.37-rc6+ (user@user) (gcc version 3.4.5) #1 Tue Jan 11 22:10:00 IST 2011
command line: root=/dev/hda3 ro 
memory layout at init:
  memory_limit : 00000000 (16 MB aligned)
  alloc_bottom : 00ea3000
  alloc_top    : 08000000
  alloc_top_hi : 08000000
  rmo_top      : 08000000
  ram_top      : 08000000
found display   : /pci@80000000/QEMU,VGA@1, opening... done
copying OF device tree...
Building dt strings...
Building dt structure...
Device tree strings 0x00ea4000 -> 0x00ea43b0
Device tree struct  0x00ea5000 -> 0x00ea7000
Calling quiesce...
returning from prom_init
```

Thanks,

Comment: VM in a VM on a host is pretty much completely unsupported and I'm having a hard time imagining why you would want to do this. Have you checked with the QEmu people to see if they're aware of a good reason this will not work?

Comment: Qemu uses Binary Translation to provide virtualization so, its basically software virtualization. And so, I think it should not be a problem to run qemu over qemu.

Answer (score 1):

When you use -nographic you cannot see the boot progress.

It usually takes a very long time from "returning from prom_init" to "Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 debian-powerpc ttyPZ0".

Comment: This would be verifiable by looking at the CPU usage, if the outer qemu does not already eat it up.